# construction Lyapunov function for global asymptotic stable systems

Tags: convex-optimization, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

We know that converse Lyapunov theorems for the conditions that a system is golobal asymptotic stable insure diferentiable Lyapunov functions. In the below I have a nonlinear system that is global asymptotic stable:
\begin{gather}\label{equ.3}
\begin{aligned}
&{\dot{x\ }}_1=-x_1\\
&+h\left(x_1\right)({x_2}^2+{x_3}^2\sin^2\left(e^{x_1}\right)+{x_2}^4{{\mathrm{cos}}^2 (\mathrm{ln}\mathrm{}(1+x^2_1))\ }+{x_2}^2{x_3}^2),  \\
&\dot{x_2}=-x_2+x^3_3+x^4_3+x_1x_3, \\
&\dot{x_3}=-x_3-x^2_3x_2-x^3_3x_2-x_1x_2,
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
where
\begin{equation}\label{equ.4}
h(x_1)=
\begin{cases}
100\frac{\sin^2(x_1)}{x_1},\quad x_1\neq 0\\
0, \quad x_1=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
To the best of my knowledge, using methods such as the gradient algorithm, sum of square, and Yoshizawa construction fail to compute the Lyapunov functions. I will be grateul if one propose me suitale Lyapunov function.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you know that there system is globally asymptotic stable?

Comment: linearization around the origin infers that this system is locally asymptotically stable, in this situation, we must find a locally Lyapunov function.

Comment: in the question, you stated that the system is _globally_ assymptotic stable. Your linearization approach can only show _local_ assymptotic stability. Do I understand it correctly that, in contradiction to the original question, you don't know if the system is GAS and that it would be sufficient for you to find a local Lyapunov function?

Comment: Thanks, It is correct that the linearization infers only local asymptotic stability. Simulation results show that it convergenses to the origin for any initial conditions although it is not a eligibe reason.

Comment: Thanks, It is correct that the linearization infers only local asymptotic stability. Simulation results show that it convergenses to the origin for any initial conditions although it is not a eligibe reason. I mean, for the conditions that system is only local asymptotic stable, convese Lyapunov theorems insure Lyapunov functions, as a result, for the mentioned system we must find Lyapunov function. If it is possible for you, propose a Lyapunov function to prove local asymptotic stability. Due to the system has an equilibrium point at the origin, it probably help to prove GAS.

Comment: So, probably you have shown for the linearization that all eigenvalues have negative real parts. You can now use the set of eigen vectors to define a coordinate transformation of the linearized system. In case all eigenvalues are real, this results in d/dt x=Ax, with A a diagonal matrix with  negative reals on the diagonal (the EVs). Then, x'*x would be a Lyapunov function. Then, simply transform back to original coords. For complex EV, these always come in complex conjugated pairs. Using this, the extension becomes easy.

Comment: PS: the construction is described in more detail and generality at the beginning of https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01231456/document

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The proposed method and paper for construction Lyapunov function are very helpful but I am following these methods and cannot find suitable Lyapunov functions. In addition, the methods such as gradient and sum of square cannot help. I will be grateful if you propse another method for construction Lyapunov function or introduce suitable Lyapunov function.

Comment: Where exactly do you fail when trying the method in the reference?

Comment: The functions such as $\sin,\cos ln()$ terns into positive parts, as a result, the derivative of Lyapunov function is not sign definite.

Comment: Who can help me?please if one can help, answer the above question.

Comment: They are not even sign definite _locally_, around 0? Remember,  you are only searching a local Lyapunov function...

Answer (score 3):

Let's attempt to find a suitable Lyapunov function in the form:

\begin{equation}
V(x) = ax_1^2 + bx_2^2 + cx_3^2
\end{equation}

Now, calculate the time derivative of V(x) along the trajectories of the system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{V}(x) &= 2ax_1\dot{x}_1 + 2bx_2\dot{x}_2 + 2cx_3\dot{x}_3 \\
&= 2ax_1\left(-x_1 + h(x_1)(x_2^2 + x_3^2\sin^2(e^{x_1}) + x_2^4\cos^2(\ln(1+x_1^2)) + x_2^2x_3^2)\right) \\
&\quad + 2bx_2\left(-x_2 + x_3^3 + x_3^4 + x_1x_3\right) \\
&\quad + 2cx_3\left(-x_3 - x_3^2x_2 - x_3^3x_2 - x_1x_2\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Now, try to determine values for a, b, and c that make $\dot{V}(x)$ negative definite ($i.e., \dot{V}(x) < 0$ for all $x$ except at the equilibrium point). This may involve algebraic manipulations and solving inequalities. Numerical methods or computer algebra systems may be needed to find suitable values for a, b, c.

For example:
Consider the simplified system:

\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= -x_1 + h(x_1)(x_2^2 + x_3^2) \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_2 + x_1x_3 \\
\dot{x}_3 &= -x_3 - x_2x_3
\end{align}

with

h(x_1) =
\begin{cases}
100\frac{\sin^2(x_1)}{x_1},\quad x_1\neq 0\\
0, \quad x_1=0.
\end{cases}

We want to find a Lyapunov function of the form:

$V(x) = ax_1^2 + bx_2^2 + cx_3^2$

where a, b, c are positive constants.

Calculate the time derivative of V along the trajectories of the system:

\begin{align}
\dot{V}(x) &= 2ax_1\dot{x}_1 + 2bx_2\dot{x}_2 + 2cx_3\dot{x}_3 \\
&= 2ax_1\left(-x_1 + h(x_1)(x_2^2 + x_3^2)\right) \nonumber \\
&\quad + 2bx_2\left(-x_2 + x_1x_3\right) \nonumber \\
&\quad + 2cx_3\left(-x_3 - x_2x_3\right)
\end{align}

Now, let's choose suitable values for a, b, c to make $\dot{V}(x)$ negative definite. For simplicity, we'll choose:

$a = 1, b = 1, c = 1.$

Now, simplify $\dot{V}(x)$:

\begin{align}
\dot{V}(x) &= -2x_1^2 + 2h(x_1)x_1(x_2^2 + x_3^2) - 2x_2^2 - 2x_3^2 - 2x_2x_3 \nonumber
\end{align}

To analyze stability, we want to ensure that $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ for all x except at the equilibrium point (0, 0, 0). However, finding suitable values for a, b, c that guarantee this can be challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Lyapunov function $V(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{1}{2}x_1^{2} + \frac{100+b}{2}\left(x_3^{2} + x_3^{2}\right)$.

\begin{align}
\dot{V} &= x_1\left(-x_1+h\left(x_1\right)({x_2}^2+{x_3}^2\sin^2\left(e^{x_1}\right)+{x_2}^4{{\mathrm{cos}}^2 (\mathrm{ln}\mathrm{}(1+x^2_1))\ }+{x_2}^2{x_3}^2)\right) \\
&\quad + (100+b)x_2\left(-x_2+x^3_3+x^4_3+x_1x_3\right) \\
&\quad + (100+b)x_3\left( -x_3-x^2_3x_2-x^3_3x_2-x_1x_2 \right) \\
&\leq -x^2_1 + 100\sin^2(x_1)({x_2}^2+{x_3}^2\sin^2\left(e^{x_1}\right)+{x_2}^4{{\mathrm{cos}}^2 (\mathrm{ln}\mathrm{}(1+x^2_1))\ }+{x_2}^2{x_3}^2) \\
&\quad -(100+b)x^2_2 -(100+b)x^2_3 \\
&\leq -x^2_1 + 100({x_2}^2+{x_3}^2 + {x_2}^4 +{x_2}^2{x_3}^2) -(100+b)x^2_2 -(100+b)x^2_3 \\
&\leq -x^2_1 + 100({x_2}^4 +{x_2}^2{x_3}^2) -bx^2_2 -bx^2_3
\end{align}
Using the fact that $pq \leq \frac{a}{2}p + \frac{1}{2a}q$, then $x^2_2x^2_3 \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}x^4_2 + \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}x^4_3$ and,
\begin{align}
\dot{V} &\leq -x^2_1 + \frac{100}{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}({x_2}^4 +{x_3}^4) -bx^2_2 -bx^2_3 \\
&\leq -x^2_1 - x_2^2(b-Cx_2^2) - x_3^2(b-Cx_3^2)
\end{align}
where $C = \frac{100}{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}$. Therefore, if $x_2, x_3 \leq \sqrt{\frac{b}{C}}$ then $\dot{V} \leq 0$. Notice that for $W(x_2,x_3) = \frac{1}{2}(x_2^2+x_3^2)$ that,
\begin{align}
\dot{W} &= -x^2_2 - x_3^2 = -2W
\end{align}
Showing that the distance of $(x_2,x_3)$ to (0,0) is always decreasing. If $x^2_2 + x_3^2 \leq \frac{b}{C}$ then $x_2, x_3 \leq \sqrt{\frac{b}{C}}$ for all $t\geq 0$. This means that $\dot{V} \leq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$ if $x_2$ and $x_3$ are initialized such that, $x^2_2(0) + x_3^2(0) \leq \frac{b}{C}$. Lastly, notice that $b$ can be selected arbitrarily large. Therefore, for any finite initial condition $(x_1(0),x_2(0),x_3(0))$ we can select a $b$ such that $\dot{V}\leq 0$.